# failed to input and run python code with sys and threading lib

Tags: python

I'm taking the coursera course for data structure. Based on a sample code,

```
 # python3

import threading


def compute_height(n, parents):
    # Replace this code with a faster implementation
    max_height = 0
    for vertex in range(n):
        height = 0
        current = vertex
        while current != -1:
            height += 1
            current = parents[current]
        max_height = max(max_height, height)
    return max_height


def main():
    n = int(input())
    parents = list(map(int, input().split()))
    print(compute_height(n, parents))


# In Python, the default limit on recursion depth is rather low,
# so raise it here for this problem. Note that to take advantage
# of bigger stack, we have to launch the computation in a new thread.
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**7)  # max depth of recursion
threading.stack_size(2**27)   # new thread will get stack of such size
threading.Thread(target=main).start()
```

I couldn't really run it with proper input or using the echo:

```
echo "5 \n 4 -1 4 1 1" | python tree_height.py
```

which generates the result:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xiang\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\xiang\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "tree_height.py", line 21, in main
    n = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"5 \\n 4 -1 4 1 1" '
```

I'm fairly new so not sure about the environment here. Could someone point out the problems?
Best

Comment: A newline cannot not be converted to an int in python like that. That's what the error says. Just process it correctly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. The error message tells you exactly what the problem is. What is unclear about that? As well, you need to make a [mre], which I think would be just two lines.

Comment: Oh wait, this has nothing to do with Python. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the code I'm inferring you want to print one integer on one line, then a space-separated list of integers on the next line.

The problem has nothing to do with Python but the shell you're calling it from:

```sh
$ echo "5 \n 4 -1 4 1 1"
5 \n 4 -1 4 1 1
```

You're expecting `echo` to act like `echo -e` and expand escape sequences. Simply use this:

```sh
$ echo -e "5\n4 -1 4 1 1"
5
4 -1 4 1 1
```

Or if your shell doesn't support `echo -e`, try `printf`:

```sh
$ printf "5\n4 -1 4 1 1\n"
5
4 -1 4 1 1
```

---

P.S. In the future, please make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which in this case is just this:

```
print(int(input()))
print(list(map(int, input().split())))
```

Comment: I see what you meant and solved it. Thank you a lot.
Also thanks for informing the minimal reproducible example